# How to rename breadcrumb text in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

> How to rename breadcrumb text from `Home` to `Store Name`?

Please see the text highlighted in **yellow circle.**
I am using **Ultimo theme.**
[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple store?

Comment: Only one store. No multiple stores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such a case, we can use [translations](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html) and it is the best and easy solution. See more at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

Create `{langauge_code}.csv`at your theme directory. Refer blow

```
 __/app
     |__/code
     |__/design
       |__/frontend
         |__/<Vendor>
           |__/<theme>
             |__/i18n
               |-- {langauge_code}.csv
```

then add the on the csv  `"Home", "My store"` , means add `Home` at first column  and add `My store`  to the second column 
after that Run the deploy command to get localization changes:

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Nicely described answer.  +1